# Else or elif condition executed every time in python code in the nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to execute below code wherein I want to insert a key in the dictionary with a particular value on a condition where tos is greater than or less than the value of position key in the dictionary. But in the output I see the else or elif condition executed every time.

```
def convert_csv_to_dataframe_and_then_convert_csv_data_to_dictionary(tos):
    recs = {0: {'POSITION': 650886123, 'is_valid': False}, 1: {'POSITION': 650886121, 'is_valid': False}}

    for i in recs:
        if int(recs[i]['POSITION'])>tos:
            recs[i]['is_valid']=True
        elif int(recs[i]['POSITION'])<tos:
            recs[i]['is_valid'] = False
    print(recs)


convert_csv_to_dataframe_and_then_convert_csv_data_to_dictionary(6508861232)
```

Below is the output.

```
{
  0: { 
  'POSITION': 650886123, 
  'is_valid': False}, 

  1: {
  'POSITION': 650886121, 
  'is_valid': False}
}
```

I have passed tos as 6508861232 which is greater than 650886123 and the other position key value in the dictionary but the is_valid is not added as True in the dictionary. Am I missing something in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine:

```
if int(recs[i]['POSITION'])>tos:
    recs[i]['is_valid']=True 
elif int(recs[i]['POSITION'])<tos:
    recs[i]['is_valid'] = False
```

In both the cases `int(recs[i]['POSITION'])<tos`, thus
`recs[i]['is_valid'] = False`

You might want to change the positions of True and False to get desired behavior as:

```
if int(recs[i]['POSITION'])>tos:
    recs[i]['is_valid'] = False 
elif int(recs[i]['POSITION'])<tos:
    recs[i]['is_valid'] = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the numbers (values of 'POSITION') in your dataframe have 9 digits. The `tos` has 10 digits.

So the output you got is correct.